# Tomcat-embed-jasper added but jsp pages Whitelabel 404 Error

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data

When I added `tomcat-embed-jasper` dependency my project got red color means 
  ERROR in Project. Then, when I run my Project, got `Error: Could not find or load main class`

**Dependency** are:

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
  </dependency>
```

**application.properties** are:

`spring.mvc.view.prefix = /WEB-INF/views/`
 `spring.mvc.view.suffix = .jsp`

I don't know what the problem is?  Please Suggest.

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: Is there any error message given?

Comment: upload your code in gihub and provide the link ...